# List all previous Years and measure till today such that all 12 Month data is available for year.Else exclude the year

Tags: sql, mdx, analysis

We have a typical Date Dimension.

I am struggling to write an `MDX` to list the Dim.Year dimension member and  measure contain data strictly for all month.(from Jan-Dec) otherwise exclude the year?.

Comment: can you show the query ???

Comment: This is a very vague request. People will probably vote to close it unless you add some more detail and also show us your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Returns this:

[image]

If I just now add in `NON EMPTY` I should get rid of 2009 and 2010:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Now returns:

[image]

The above is a very simple example.
Other scenarios might require us to get rid of `null`s using other functions such as `FILTER` / `NonEmpty` / `HAVING` / `IIF`.

---

Edit

To just return years that have 12 months with data I've written the following (a wee bit more complicated than the above!). I will try to simplify later although you will definitely require an additional measure to achieve your goal,

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[cntMths] AS 
    Count
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        Descendants
        (
          [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
         ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month]
         ,SELF
        )
       ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
  } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS HAVING 
  [Measures].[cntMths] = 12 ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

---

Edit (for @sourav_agasti)

This is a solution against `Adventure Works` which only uses attribute hierarchies i.e. for a cube without a well formed Date dimension:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[cntMths] AS 
    Count
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
          [Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember
        * 
          [Date].[Month of Year].[Month of Year].MEMBERS
       ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,[Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS HAVING 
  [Measures].[cntMths] = 12 ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This is the equivalent to Sourav's script using the above method:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[cntMths] AS 
    Count
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
          [Dim Year].[Year].CurrentMember
        * 
          [Dim Month].[Month].MEMBERS
       ,[Measures].[Foo]
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,[Dim Year].[Year].[Year].MEMBERS HAVING 
  [Measures].[cntMths] = 12 ON 1
FROM [Your Cube];
```

---

**Further Edit**

I chanced on an article last night which gives a more efficient method. Apparently `Count - NonEmpty` which I've done above is not tuned to work in block calculation mode whereas `Sum -IIF` is. So here is a quicker alternative using the later method:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[cntMths - S] AS 
    Sum
    (
      [Date].[Month of Year].[Month of Year].MEMBERS
     ,IIF
      (
        IsEmpty([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
       ,null
       ,1
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[cntMths - S]} ON 0
 ,[Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS HAVING 
  [Measures].[cntMths - S] = 12 ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. AS I can see 2009 and 2010

Comment: I am looking for list of Year which contain data for all months ranges from Jan-Dec. If  any month data is missing for e.g. if there is data only for Month Jan and Feb and no data from March to December then this year should not appear in list.

Comment: @user37860 ok - now things get interesting!! I'll play later and edit answer.

Comment: @ whytheq,Sourav_Agasti  Thank you so much for the ans.Its great to have Friends and experts like yours .The helping hands in the shades of MDX.

Comment: @user37860 - if you appreciate mine and sourav's effort then you can up ^ each of our attempts. If one of the attempts works then you can tick as answer. If one attempt is close to the answer then you can comment and get further edits from either me or sourav. (by the way - I upped your question)

Comment: @user37860 I believe it would be good manners to up ^ the answer of @sourav_agasti answer - if he spent 3hrs on it - he contributes a lot to the `mdx` answers on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I took it as a challenge to write a code which gets you the result without there being any hierarchies anywhere. So here goes my attempt(after few hours of madness!).

You must be having a `[Dim Month]` dimension too. I am assuming the data there is stored like `Dec-2014` or `Dec 2014`. Basically assuming that the last 4 digits give the year.
Now, one way you can figure out the years having data is to first list out all the months which **don't** have data and then figuring out the year for these months and then **NOT** displaying these years in the final output.

The below code does that for you:

```
WITH SET MonthsWithNoData AS
FILTER([Dim Month].[Month].CHILDREN, [Measures].[foo] = 0)

MEMBER [Measures].Year as
RIGHT([Dim Month].[Month].CURRENTMEMBER.member_value, 4)

SET SetOfYearsWithNoData AS
GENERATE(MonthsWithNoData, STRTOSET("[Dim Year].[Year].&[" + RIGHT(MonthsWithNoData.currentmember.member_value, 4) + "]"))

SET SetOfYearsWithData AS
([Dim Year].[Year].MEMBERS - SetOfYearsWithNoData)

member yearValues as
[Dim Year].[Year].currentmember.member_value

member wellFormedyearValues as
[Dim Year].[Year].currentmember.member_unique_name

SELECT {yearvalues, wellFormedyearValues} on 0, 
SetOfYearsWithData on 1
from [Your cube]
```

I agree that the final output does not look too beautiful though. Having said that, a hierarchy would make the code much less complicated and the MDX would be much simpler. A `[Calender]` dimension with requisite hierarchies in place(as assumed in @whytheq's answer) would be the better approach in terms of elegance as well as performance.

Comment: I think it is ok to assume User Hierarchies being in place for Date dimensions, so why challenge yourself to this madness? (although I reckon I can do something cleaner only using attribute hierarchies ...I'll give it a go :) )

Comment: Well for one, it hasn't been mentioned and second, what's the fun in that? ;-)  And yes, I believe cleaner solutions are possible, it's just that I am back to SO(and MDX) after a long break and it's just not striking me!

Comment: glad you're back @sourav_agasti - I was getting bored without you.

Comment: ok - I edited my answer with a script just using user hierarchies (that doesn't manipulate member_values either!)